# Converting to for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

How can I convert this code to a for loop so if I could add more forces and moments? This is a lot code and its basically computing the unit vector and finding the sum of the forces in the x direction, y direction and z direction and doing the same for the moments.

This is only for one particular case so I want to put it in a for loop so when new forces are applied they will be accounted for.

Any help or nudge in the right direction would be a huge help! Thanks in advance.

```
load ('inputdata.mat')

A= zeros(6,6);
B= zeros (6,1);


% Calculate Force in x,y,z direction, sums them and puts them in the B 
% vector positions 1,2,3 

NF1=((ForceDir(1,2))^2+(ForceDir(1,3))^2+(ForceDir(1,4))^2)^(1/2);

F1i=(ForceDir(1,2)/NF1)* ForceDir(1,1);

F1j=(ForceDir(1,3)/NF1)* ForceDir(1,1);

F1k=(ForceDir(1,4)/NF1)*ForceDir(1,1);

NF2= ((ForceDir(2,2))^2+(ForceDir(2,3))^2+(ForceDir(2,4))^2)^(1/2);

F2i=(ForceDir(2,2)/NF2)* ForceDir(2,1);

F2j=(ForceDir(2,3)/NF2)* ForceDir(2,1);

F2k=(ForceDir(2,4)/NF2)* ForceDir(2,1);

B(1,1)= F1i+F2i; %External Force in x

B(2,1)= F1j+F2j; %External Force in y

B(3,1)= F1k+F2k; %External Force in z

% Calculate Moments in x,y,z direction and puts them in B vector 
% position 3,4,5

unitvectorForce1=[F1i F1j F1k];

MomentByForce1= cross(ForceCoor(1,:),unitvectorForce1);

unitvectorForce2= [F2i F2j F2k];

MomentByForce2= cross(ForceCoor(2,:),unitvectorForce2);

MomentNormal=((DirMoment(1,2))^2+(DirMoment(1,3))^2+(DirMoment(1,4))^2)^(1/2);

M1i= (DirMoment(1,2)/MomentNormal)*DirMoment(1,1);

M1j= (DirMoment(1,3)/MomentNormal)*DirMoment (1,1);

M1k= (DirMoment(1,4)/MomentNormal)*DirMoment(1,1);

unitvectorMoment= [M1i M1j M1k];

B(4,1)= MomentByForce1(1)+MomentByForce2(1)+ unitvectorMoment(1)

B(5,1)= MomentByForce1(2)+MomentByForce2(2)+ unitvectorMoment(2)

B(6,1)= MomentByForce1(3)+MomentByForce2(3)+ unitvectorMoment(3)
```

Comment: IMO: This question is impossible to help with as it stands. What's `ForceDir`, `NF1` etc? And what exactly is it you want to loop over?

Comment: Those come from a textfile I read in, 'ForceDir' is the direction the force is acting in and it is stored in a matrix so I am calling them with 'ForceDir(1,2)'. I basically made my own variables that call actually numbers in my workspace. I want to loop find NF1 and NF2 and applying that to the the direction I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correclty, this should do the trick:

```
for ii = 1:N
  NF(ii) = ((ForceDir(ii,2))^2+(ForceDir(ii,3))^2+(ForceDir(ii,4))^2)^(1/2);
  Fi(ii) = ForceDir(ii,2) / NF(ii) * ForceDir(ii,1);
  Fj(ii) = ForceDir(ii,3) / NF(ii) * ForceDir(ii,1);
  Fk(ii) = ForceDir(ii,4) / NF(ii) * ForceDir(ii,1);
  %% Etc
end
```